# 3D Plots in R with different Varaible

Tags: r, 3d

I have a data frame with month server name and some data for server

```
            Jan Feb Mar
Server A    20% 44% 12%
Server B    45% 56% 45%
Server C    56% 12% 12%
```

Can this be plotted in a 3D graph using R . Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What kind of 3D chart? A line chart, a bar chart, a pie chart? Almost any visualization is possible in R, so please be more specific.

Comment: Take a look at the `rgl` package for 3D plotting.

Comment: I am looking for something like of a volcano or wire mesh graph